# Casting to decimal in Teradata/SQL

Tags: sql, casting, decimal, teradata

I'm trying to cast a line in a (Teradata) SQL query so I can get decimals:

```
 (SUM((vndr_po_ln_vb.mnfst_qty - vndr_po_ln_vb.rcvd_qty)))/(CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT vndr_po_vb.vndr_po_num)) AS DECIMAL(3,2))  AS "Average Damaged Cases per PO"
```

However, it seems that it it throwing back an error:

```
Syntax error: expected something between ')' and ')'.
```

Am I correctly casting this line of code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got too many parens and in the wrong places:

```
SUM(vndr_po_ln_vb.mnfst_qty - vndr_po_ln_vb.rcvd_qty)
/ CAST(COUNT(DISTINCT vndr_po_vb.vndr_po_num) AS DECIMAL(3, 2)) AS "Average Damaged Cases per PO"
```

But this will fail if the count returns more than 10.